# Send a Picture of my ID and a selfie of me holding it to a Questionable Website

Tags: privacy, identity, identity-theft

Some website asked for the verification of my identity to make a purchase of online goods. I didn't think twice and send them a picture of both sides of my country's ID (not USA) and a selfie holding it to the website asked to submit. When I went to the FAQ I noticed something was wrong with the website https://validmy.id/faq
Now I'm worried with the usage of my identity in fraudulent transactions or criminal activities.
Is there something I can do to prevent my identity theft? Report my identity as stolen or denounce the website?

**Edit:** forgot to say I also send them a selfie holding the ID

Comment: Ideally, no any online shopping platform ask you to prove your identity, Incase if we want to use their wallet then they need to verify you via proper KYC standard procedure. You can report this incident. Denouncing may also help to save many from this trap.

Comment: How do I denounce them? I live in South America.

Comment: What specifically is wrong with the website that makes you suspicious of the request, other than traditional privacy concerns?

Comment: There's nothing intrinsically wrong with the website, but the fact I send them enough information to allow them to identify as me (they can take loans at a bank with my name for example).